# Android File Class mkdirs with relative paths doesn't working as like absolute paths

Tags: java, android

I want to create directory using relative paths in android. But it fails using relative paths. I got success only after absolute path.

Sample Code : (Relative Path)(Not working for directory, Working for files)

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());

File logDirectory = new File("sample");
// Success will be always false here.
boolean success = logDirectory.mkdirs();

// But I got success in file creation with relative path.
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("sample.txt");
fos.write(1);
fos.close();
```

Sample Code : (Absolute Path)(Working in both files and folder)

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());

File logDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/sample");
// Success will be always true here.
boolean success = logDirectory.mkdirs();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("sample.txt");
fos.write(1);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Please note that I found posted issue in android issue tracker. Please check below link.                                                                       https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32997

Comment: Why are you messing around with `user.dir`?